# Run normally 3-phase robot with batteries and single-phase domestic supply?

Tags: batteries, three-phase

Apparently relatively small industrial robots (such as e.g. a Kuka with 12 - 20kg payload) require a  peak 15kW electric supply that is used only to that peak at startup, and then much less electricity is  used in normal use (or slow/light use as e.g. 3D ceramic printing).

Is there an electronics work-around (e.g. an AXIstorage modular battery with appropriate auxiliary electronics) that would allow me to run such a robot (with a peak 15kW supply requirement at start-up) with a single-phase household supply? I'm thinking fully charge a battery which can deal with a short-lived peak of 15kW and use that to start the robot, then have an appropriate auxiliary installation so the robot runs even though the background supply is single-phase.

Comment: Define "short-lived" peak of 15kW.

Comment: A rare and expensive beast but a 15 kW capable three phase UPS which could be configured to accept single phase input (bridge your single phase to all three phase inputs) may do the job for you. How about just an inrush current limiter using halogen bulbs during startup and bridge over them with a relay after that?

Comment: Which kuka controller are you using?

Comment: I haven't got the Kuka yet, Bryan! I can't get it until the electricity supply hurdle is solved. But basically the highest payload Kuka that runs on the single-phase KRC4 compact controller is the 10Kg payload KR 10 R1420. A bit too small for the sort of thing I have in mind. But if you look at the Kuka KR 20 R1810-2 or KR 22 R1610, either of those would be ideal for me - but with that increase in payload comes the move to the standard KRC4 controller, which expects a 3-phase power supply.

Answer (score 1):

The robot's power supplies most likely internally run from rectified AC, i.e. from DC. So you don't need to do anything super fancy in terms of generating 3 phase AC power or anything like that. In fact, if you did, it'd be rather inefficient and a waste of effort too.

For a 120VAC mains voltage, investigate connecting a 240VDC battery directly to the input terminals, and using an external PFC stage to keep the battery charged and provide a somewhat better behaved load for domestic use. The PFC module would need to be configured for 240V - higher voltages are not necessary unless the robot's original input is configured for 220VAC. In that case, the PFC would need to have its output set to 350-360VDC.

You likely need to bypass the input rectifiers in the motor inverters, since when powered from DC, the diodes won't be sharing the dissipation, and may overheat and fail. Your external power source - a 2kW PFC module and a battery - provide DC already, so no need to waste energy on a redundant rectification. For 120VAC market, you'd design the input to be rated 15A, with an IEC 320-C20 power entry module. An IEC 320-C19 to NEMA 5-20P would be the power cord.

Motor controllers fed from 3 phases usually do "dead phase" detection to protect the rectifier. You'd need to bypass this circuit, or rather feed it the voltages needed to make it happy.

So, there will be plenty of reverse engineering involved on the input side of the robot's power supply, but the solutions should be off-the-shelf for the most part. The battery, presuming that it's lithium, will need to be of course kept balanced with balancing circuits, and a charge controller would be controlling the PFC module's output voltage to carry out the charging process. This would probably be a lowest-cost solution in terms of parts, with most availability, but it's not anything "plug and play".

With lead-acid deep cycle batteries, things get easier, as the PFC module can be set to a fixed voltage, with the battery bank connected in parallel to the DC link. I still highly suggest using a charge balancing circuit on each battery, so that they last longer.

Comment: Really pleased to have received this reply, KHFM, it's given me hope that it's worth chasing further and possibly actually doing! I'll try to understand your answer and take it as a starting point for not being turned away by any professionals I approach about it here in Spain! Thank you very much.